# Prove that the mean of all vectors is a centroid

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a nudge in the right direction: I am trying to prove that a vector is the mean for all vectors in some d-dimensional space is the centroid of the space.  The distance between vectors is characterized as (xi-xj)^2.  I know that for k an element of X, the centroid =(x1+x2...xn)/n and I have tried inputing that into the distance function, setting the distance function to 0 and solving for the minimum but that ended up with a negative distance which I don't think is right.  I really don't want anyone to solve the problem, but maybe point out where I might be going wrong or something I may have missed.